# Is 'with which' used correctly in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, phrase-usage

> This is a new technology based on Georges Charpak’s research on gaseous particle detection with a multi-wire proportional chamber **with which** he won the Nobel Prize in 1992.

I'm trying to explain that George Charpak developed this new technology and that he won the Nobel Prize for this discovery. But I trying to write as fluent as possible in this phrase. Is 'with which' used correctly in this sentence?

Comment: I would use "for which", though am not sure.

Comment: @Will is right. He won the prize **for** his work. The work, for which he won the prize, ...

Answer (score 3):

You get a *Nobel prize* or *Grammy* or any reward **for something** not **with something**.

**With** refers to "**together**" or "**in company**" which don't really fit here.

You actually answered your own doubt in your second paragraph:

> I'm trying to explain that George Charpak developed this new technology and that **he won the Nobel Prize for this discovery**. But I trying to write as fluent as possible in this phrase.

Comment: Contrast with: _"This is a new technology based on Georges Charpak’s research on gaseous particle detection with a multi-wire proportional chamber, **with** which he won the 1992 World Gaseous Particle Detection Pro/Am Championships."_